# How to generate a list of Langford pairings?

Tags: combinatorics

I am wondering how to make a function that makes a list of Langford pairings named LangfordPairings that takes an integer n as output and if Langford pairings exist for that number, they output the list for that number.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing

The output of the function should be a list.

I did find a [Python program](https://susam.net/blog/langford-pairing.html).

```
def find_solutions(n, s=None):
    # If called from top-level (s=None), create a list of 2n zero
    # values. Zeroes represent unoccupied cells.
    if s is None:
        s = [0] * (2 * n)

    # Next number to be placed.
    m = max(s) + 1

    # For each i, try to place m at s[i] and s[i + m + 1].
    for i in range(2 * n - m - 1):

        # If s[i] and s[i + m + 1] are unoccupied, ...
        if s[i] == s[i + m + 1] == 0:

            # first place m at s[i] and s[i + m + 1].
            s[i] = s[i + m + 1] = m

            # If m is the last number to be placed, ...
            if m == n:
                # then a solution has been found; yield it.
                yield s[:]
            else:
                # else try to place the next number.
                yield from find_solutions(n, s)

            # Undo placement of m.
            s[i] = s[i + m + 1] = 0


# Count solutions for 1 <= n <= 12.
for n in range(1, 13):
    count = sum(1 for s in find_solutions(n))
    print('n = {:2} => {:6} solutions'.format(n, count))
```

There's also a [challenge on a coding site about this](https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/problems/langford-pairing_845178). Wikipedia states,

> Langford pairings exist only when n is congruent to 0 or 3 modulo 4;
> for instance, there is no Langford pairing when n = 1, 2, or 5.
>
> As Knuth (2008) describes, the problem of listing all Langford
> pairings for a given n can be solved as an instance of the exact cover
> problem, but for large n the number of solutions can be calculated
> more efficiently by algebraic methods.

Comment: Have you tried converting the Python code to the Wolfram Language?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I felt uncomfortable about how I was just referencing work someone else did without really adding anything of my own. I did try to cite them as best as possible but I feel this is best as just a comment. [This notebook](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/IntegerSequences/LangfordsProblem.nb) from the MathWorld page on Langford's Problem generates a Langford sequence for each positive integer input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it using `ResourceFunction["SelectPermutations"]`, however it is not particularly fast:

```
isLangford[list_, n_] := (1 + Subtract @@@ Partition[Ordering[list], 2]) == -Range[n]
perms = With[{n = 4},
   ResourceFunction["SelectPermutations"][
    Riffle[Range[n], Range[n]], isLangford[#, n] &
   ]]

(** {{2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2}} **)
```

Here is a much faster way to do it with `ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"]`. It's faster because it discards intermediate results that cannot possibly become Langford. It's instantaneous for `n=4` so here's it working harder for `n=7`

```
Remove["Global`*"]
isLangford[list_, n_] := (1 + Subtract @@@ Partition[Ordering[list], 2]) == -Range[n]
isSemiLangford[list_] := AllTrue[DeleteDuplicates[list],
  With[{pos = Flatten[Position[list, #], 1]},
    Switch[Length[pos],
     1, True,
     2, (1 + (Subtract @@ pos)) == -#,
     _, False]] &]

perms = With[{n = 7},
   ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"][
    Table[Range[n], {2 n}],
    isSemiLangford, isLangford[#, n] &
    , All]];

Length[perms]
(** 52 **)
```

Here is an even faster method that uses `ResourceFunction["FindExactCover"]`. The way to represent it as an exact cover is discussed in *Knuth - The Art of Computer Programming Vol IV*. We are essentially creating bitvectors of length $3n$ for the sets. The first $n$ bits are 1-hot encoded (1 bit is enabled) to indicate which number we are dealing with, and the remaining $2n$ bits in the vector are 2-hot encoded (two bits enabled) to indicate which positions are allowed for that number.

This is hugely faster than the above methods and takes only a few seconds for $n=8$:

```
Remove["Global`*"];
exactCoverTriples[n_] := Table[
  Prepend[#, k] & /@ 
   Select[Subsets[Range[2 n], {2}], Subtract @@ # == -k - 1 &], {k, 1,
    n}]
generateExactCoverProblem[n_] :=
 Flatten[Table[
   Normal[SparseArray[Thread[(# + {0, n, n}) -> 1], {3 n}]] & /@ g
   , {g, exactCoverTriples[n]}
   ], 1]
convertBitvecsToSeq[bv_] := With[{n = Length[First@bv]/3},
  Normal@
   SparseArray[
    Flatten[Thread[
        Flatten[Position[#[[n + 1 ;;]], 1]] -> 
         FirstPosition[#[[;; n]], 1][[1]]] & /@ bv]]
  ]

results = convertBitvecsToSeq /@ ResourceFunction["FindExactCover"][
  generateExactCoverProblem[8], All
  ];
Length[results]
(** 300 **)
```

n = 2...10 takes about 16 seconds on my machine.

```
Table[
  {i, Length[
    convertBitvecsToSeq /@ 
     ResourceFunction["FindExactCover"][generateExactCoverProblem[i], 
      All]]},
  {i, 2, 10}] // Timing

(** {16.2969, {{2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 52}, {8, 300}, {9, 0}, {10, 0}}} **)
```

When just finding a single solution, I find it starts becoming a lot slower above n=24:

```
convertBitvecsToSeq[ResourceFunction["FindExactCover"][generateExactCoverProblem[24]]]
(** {24, 21, 23, 18, 15, 2, 14, 8, 2, 4, 20, 5, 11, 22, 4, 17, 8, 5, 16, 19, 15, 14, 18, 21, 11, 24, 23, 13, 9, 12, 6, 20, 7, 17, 10, 16, 22, 6, 9, 19, 7, 13, 12, 3, 1, 10, 1, 3} **)
```

Comment: If you don't need all of them, then just remove the `, All`.

Answer (score 2):

Direct translation of the Python code provided by you into Mathematica code:

```mathematica
FindSolutions[n_Integer, s_List : {}] := 
 Module[{sNew = s, m, solutions = {}, i}, 
  If[sNew == {}, sNew = ConstantArray[0, 2 n]];
  m = Max[sNew] + 1;
  For[i = 1, i <= 2*n - m - 1, i++, 
   If[sNew[[i]] == 0 && sNew[[i + m + 1]] == 0, 
    sNew[[i]] = m;
    sNew[[i + m + 1]] = m;
    If[m == n, 
     AppendTo[solutions, sNew], 
     solutions = Join[solutions, FindSolutions[n, sNew]]
    ];
    sNew[[i]] = 0;
    sNew[[i + m + 1]] = 0;
   ];
  ];
  solutions
]

CountSolutions[n_Integer] := Length[FindSolutions[n]]

Do[
 Print["n = ", n, " => ", CountSolutions[n], " solutions"],
 {n, 1, 12}
]
```

(So slow, [only output results for $n=1..=10$ within 60 seconds on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVFda8IwFH3Przj0wYdZQX3UdSAOwaFjsL2FIGXNNGBvpI1so/jbu5u0leK2h4RwPu65NzdP3UHnqTPvaV2vDGWv9nh2xlIpabcmp/e6iFHuNqZ0mKG6KMwSCGxtdj5qWZXP@hMJyhg5yzovI9UlhuEjgPWHbGQN2lqWrHMpuUVRpN9yHGMKUmrO@pzZbfoVTApDTDy4soU0TEy4LO4TTO8II5aOAjIchqQuSkqjlM8bYzBAi3Cl3FdrmcaAnhz5vA/19R3F9XPvptaNxemkKXuz8jp7M6DqBP0/ebKG@sKb/26dKhjV/Fd74//ba6jgCdc1RCghlvZM7o@9hlVuNO3dQd60wk2IRysFXgpDTkbEGVHsx46QPPjnbVHlqWtspGKBiuW8nMn0IlRd/wA).
Any improvement would be appreciated.)

By the way, the port of your Python code in Rust:

```rust
fn find_solutions(n: usize) -> Vec<Vec<usize>> {
    fn place_number(s: &mut Vec<usize>, n: usize, m: usize, solutions: &mut Vec<Vec<usize>>) {
        for i in 0..(2 * n - m - 1) {
            if s[i] == 0 && s[i + m + 1] == 0 {
                s[i] = m;
                s[i + m + 1] = m;
                if m == n {
                    solutions.push(s.clone());
                } else {
                    place_number(s, n, m + 1, solutions);
                }
                s[i] = 0;
                s[i + m + 1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    let mut solutions: Vec<Vec<usize>> = Vec::new();
    let mut s: Vec<usize> = vec![0; 2 * n];
    place_number(&mut s, n, 1, &mut solutions);
    solutions
}

fn main() {
    for n in 1..=12 {
        let solutions = find_solutions(n);
        println!("n = {:2} => {:6} solutions", n, solutions.len());
    }
}
```

---

Theoretically, they have same output:

```
n =  1 =>      0 solutions
n =  2 =>      0 solutions
n =  3 =>      2 solutions
n =  4 =>      2 solutions
n =  5 =>      0 solutions
n =  6 =>      0 solutions
n =  7 =>     52 solutions
n =  8 =>    300 solutions
n =  9 =>      0 solutions
n = 10 =>      0 solutions
n = 11 =>  35584 solutions
n = 12 => 216288 solutions
```